# Auto redeploy JavaScript and html files in InteliJ like Ecplipse

Tags: java

I swapped Eclipse for InteliJ but this program doesn't auto update html, css, JS files like Eclipse. How can I change this?

Comment: unclear what are u asking...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, however if I understand correctly ( a lot guess work here ) you have to make sure that you deploy your project as exploded war/ear.

Then, right click and declare as source file in the ide to each folder containing the frontend code you need to be hot swapped.

Now whenever you update resources, your frontend changes would be reflected automatically and you won't need re-deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you *make* the project after modifying files IDEA will redeploy them to a running server which should cause them to update.